Best approach to object creation in the background without using a task queue system?
I have been thinking of the best approach to a record creation in the background without using django signals, or celery, etc.
I do not want to use signals due to the fact that the sender Model would be called a very high number of times, as that table gets created/updated quite often. So I am looking to avoid this approach.
My goal is to run a function that goes through some complex logic, ultimately ending in an EmailRecordTracker object creation in which I am doing some tracking to determine whether an email needs to be sent out or not at a later point in time.
The function I need to create needs to get hit after a user submits a form and the form is fully saved.
I was looking into asynchronous support possibly.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/async/
Workflow is pretty simple:

User submits form, updates a form, etc.
User is able to continue to navigate through app while my function to create an EmailTrackerRecord gets ran in the background (ForeignKey to form submission).

Any advice would be appreciated!

Why don't you want to use a queuing system? It makes sense you wouldn't want to do signals, but celery tasks can be extremely lightweight with the right configuration. That's the 'default' solution to this problem, and it's hard to give a recommendation without knowing why it doesn't work for you.

@NickBailey unfortunately the decision is not up to me right now. That’s really the reason I’m looking for an alternative that can be short term!

Why not just fire off a separate thread or process?  Write your logic as a function.  Starting it as another thread only takes a couple lines of code.

You dont need the query, you can use different approaches:

Perform the task AFTER close the request:
 from django.http import TemplateResponse

 class DoAfterAnswer(TemplateResponse):

     def close(self):
         super().close()
         self.callback()

 class UpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
     response_class = DoAfterAnswer
     success_url = "thank_you/"

     def form_valid(self, form):
         form._save, form.save = form.save, lambda:form
         return super().form_valid(form)

     def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
         response= super().render_to_response(context, **kwargs)
         response.callback = self.object._save
         return response



In this case server finalaze answer for user, closed request and only after it perform computation.
Second possibility is to add task in crontab of your system.

Thank you! I understand this! My only issue is that I actually have about 3 views that would need to be updated. As this EmailRecordTracker is going to be created in a few places.
If I could keep this functionality out of the view and just inside my form method, I think I would be better off. That is really the only reason I am looking into the aynchronous method!

I use the solution suggested as a MixIn for my views. In this case, I am following DRY. The EmailSender function also exists in only one place in the codebase. So I can't imagine why it doesn't pass. Asynchronous code won't help in your case. You probably mean running the task in another independent thread - in that case it's not asynchronous programming. It's a different pattern called task scheduler. And i offer you  easyest way - to create cronjob for that.
